# I wrote a Angular js code but its not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my controller.js file:

```
angular.module("ngcribs").controller("cribsController", function($scope) {
scope.sc = "Hello world!"; });
```

---

and my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
        <h1>{{ sc }}</h1>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>
```

hello world is not displaying in the browser please tell me how to fix it

Comment: I'd first fix this formatting in the question. Also *"my code doesn't work"* with no explanation is off-topic. You need to explain the issue that's occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Script elements need to go into either the `<head>` or `<body>` of the page, not the `<html>` element.

Also, where is the Angular module? in app.js? It definitely exists somewhere, e.g:

```
angular.module("ngcribs", []);
```

Answer (score 0):

change angular code like below and your missing '$' at scope.sc

```
angular.module("ngCribs",[]).controller("cribsController", function($scope) {
$scope.sc = "Hello world!"; 
});
```

and ng-app should be like "ngCribs" as C is capital word in module

```
 <body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
        <h1>{{ sc }}</h1>
    </body>
```